# How do I bring a User control to the front in a form

Tags: vb.net

I have a `loginForm.vb`, and 3 user controls: `promptEmail.vb`, `promptLogin.vb`, `promptEmailRecovery.vb`.

When I launch the app I want the Login Form to load the `promptLogin.vb`  by bringing it to front.

Then when I click `forgot password` which is a button in `promptLogin.vb`, I want it to load the `promptEmailRecovery.vb` and hide the prompt login.

How can this be done?

Comment: Expose a custom public event from your UserControls that can be subscribed to from another class (a Form, here, or its controller). When, for example, the `promptLogin` UC's `ForgotThePassword` button is pressed, you raise the `ForgottenPassword` event. If/when this event is raised, the Form (or whatever subscribed to the event) knows that it's time to bring forth the UC that handles the password recovery procedure.

Comment: You can use promptLogin.Show() or promptLogin.Close() to open or close it

Answer (score 0):

Bring the login prompt to the front in the designer through its context menu there. Then it'll be in front when the form loads.

In the `.Click` event handler for the forgot password button, Call `.BringToFront()` on the `promptEmailRecovery` user control.